# XmlDocument.LoadXml() hanging for several minutes

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I have a routine that parses an XML response from an HTTP request and I use XmlDocument.LoadXml to help do this.  I count on this method throwing an exception on bad XML and returning a loaded up XmlDocument object when successful.

What I didn't expect is for it to hang for several minutes loading a document.  When I run this code in a test environment, it hangs for several minutes 100% of the time.  Looks like some bug in .NET to me...

```
    Dim tstring As String = ""

    tstring &= "" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "<html> xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" >" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "<head><title>" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "    Error" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "</title></head>" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "<body>" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "</body>" & vbCrLf
    tstring &= "</html>" & vbCrLf

    Dim MyXmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    MyXmlDoc.LoadXml(tstring)
```

The specific line in the document that can be removed to keep it from hanging is:

```
    tstring &= "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">" & vbCrLf
```

Am I going to have to search for "<!DOCTYPE html" in the string and not call LoadXml() if I see it?  My concern about this is what other gotchas are waiting for me inside this method?

Comment: Do you see the same perf hit using LINQ to XML via XElement.Load(uri) or XDocument.Parse(tstring)? Also, for future reference, try using a StringBuilder instead of excessive concatenations to build up strings.

Comment: Jim, I avoided string builder here to simplify the problem explanation.  Obviously, my code looks NOTHING like this since the XML is read from an HTTP request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the loadxml call is parsing the doctype for validation purposes so it must fetch that url - that is slow in this case. You can test [directly](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd) in your browser.

Another question [provides a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4462151/931049) - to quote:

> in .NET 4.0 XmlTextReader has a property called DtdProcessing. 
>   When set to DtdProcessing.Ignore it should disable DTD processing.

and

> doc.XmlResolver = null;

for .NET 3.5 should work.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered.  I looked at the .NET 3.5 object for a way to turn off fetching because I thought that might be the problem but there was none.

Comment: And correct for vb.net and 3.5 MyXmlDoc.XmlResolver = Nothing works

Comment: Interesting background on this issue from W3C: http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/