# How can I ignore phantom xml attributes which are creating an infinite loop when trying to rename nodes?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, .net-4.0, xml-parsing

I've been tasked with converting the results of a restful web service into an XML document with new formatting.

An example of the html/xhtml to be converted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>OvidWS Result Set Resource</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="results">
            <tr>
                <td class="_index">
                  <a class="uri" href="REDACTED">1</a>
                </td>
                <td class="au">
                  <span>GILLESPIE JB</span>
                  <span>KUKES RE</span>
                </td>
                <td class="so">A.M.A. American Journal of Diseases of Children</td>
                <td class="ti">Acetylsalicylic acid poisoning with recovery.</td>
                <td class="ui">20267726</td>
                <td class="yr">1947</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="_index">
                  <a class="uri" href="REDACTED">2</a>
                </td>
                <td class="au">BASS MH</td>
                <td class="so">Journal of the Mount Sinai Hospital, New York</td>
                <td class="ti">Aspirin poisoning in infants.</td>
                <td class="ui">20265054</td>
                <td class="yr">1947</td>
              </tr>
        </table>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Ideally all I want to do is take whatever is listed as the class attribute and make it the element name, in cases where there is no 'class' attribute I just want to mark it as an item.

This is the conversion I'm looking for:

```
<results>
    <citation>
        <_index>
            <uri href="REDACTED">1</uri>
        </_index>
        <au>
            <item>GILLESPIE JB</item>
            <item>KUKES RE</item>
        </au>
        <so>A.M.A. American Journal of Diseases of Children</so>
        <ti>Acetylsalicylic acid poisoning with recovery.</ti>
        <ui>20267726</ui>
        <yr>1947</yr>
    </citation>
    <citation>
        <_index>
            <uri href="REDACTED">2</a>
        </_index>
        <au>BASS MH</au>
        <so>Journal of the Mount Sinai Hospital, New York</so>
        <ti>Aspirin poisoning in infants.</ti>
        <ui>20265054</ui>
        <yr>1947</yr>
    </citation>
</results>
```

I found a little piece of code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/bd61735f-3fef-4e37-b133-744c7e0123fe) which allows me to rename a node:

```
    Public Shared Function RenameNode(ByVal e As XmlNode, newName As String) As XmlNode
        Dim doc As XmlDocument = e.OwnerDocument
        Dim newNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateNode(e.NodeType, newName, Nothing)
        While (e.HasChildNodes)
            newNode.AppendChild(e.FirstChild)
        End While
        Dim ac As XmlAttributeCollection = e.Attributes
        While (ac.Count > 0) 
            newNode.Attributes.Append(ac(0))
        End While
        Dim parent As XmlNode = e.ParentNode
        parent.ReplaceChild(newNode, e)
        Return newNode
    End Function
```

But a problem arises when iterating over the XmlAttributeCollection.  For some reason when looking at one of the td nodes, 2 attributes that don't appear in the source magically appear: rowspan and colspan.  It seems these attributes are messing with the iterator as when they are consumed, they do not disappear from the attribute list like the 'class' attribute does.  Instead, the value of the attribute is consumed (changing from "1" to "").  This results in an infinite loop.

I note that they are of type 'XMLUnspecifiedAttribute', but when I modify the loop to detect that:

```
While (ac.Count > 0) And Not TypeOf (ac(0)) Is System.Xml.XmlUnspecifiedAttribute
    newNode.Attributes.Append(ac(0))
End While
```

I get the following error:

```
System.Xml.XmlUnspecifiedAttribute is not accessible in this context because it is 'friend'
```

Any ideas why this is happening or how to work around it?

Comment: I'm starting to think I should be using XSLT for this, but I'm not at all familiar with it and whether it will be able to accommodate the fact that the source document has a flexible field list.  There are a total of 50 or so optional fields which may or may not appear in the source which is why I chose to do it this way.

Comment: Either you are doing it differently than I am or there is something screwy about your implementation. I copied the source you provided and I ran it through a test application and had no problems. I even ran it through adding `rowspan` and `colspan` to one of the `td` tags and still had no issue. I made the test program using the code you provided.

Comment: It's possible that it might be due to the doctype (which I didn't include in the example).  I'll update the question to include it.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: without a name space manager, the name space could be jiggering your code. I will check it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is indeed your doc type declaration.

since you are translating the nodes into something else completely then I would say you don't even need it and can [safely ignore it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428478/xmldocument-loadxml-hanging-for-several-minutes).

Since I was not including it in my tests, and then when I included it the xmlresolver went haywire, I am assuming you certainly don't need it here.

You can ignore it by setting the resolver to `nothing`:

```
{xml document object}.Xmlresolver = nothing
```

Then you do your select for the node and process. I did this even with the doc type in the source file and still had no issues.

Here is the code I used to test:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim USEDoc As New XmlDocument

    Dim theNameManager As System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager = New System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(USEDoc.NameTable)
    theNameManager.AddNamespace("xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")

    USEDoc.XmlResolver = Nothing
    USEDoc.Load("RestServ.txt")

    renameNodes(USEDoc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::xhtml:table", theNameManager))

    Dim SaveDoc As New XmlDocument
    SaveDoc.AppendChild(SaveDoc.ImportNode(USEDoc.SelectSingleNode("//results", theNameManager), True))

    SaveDoc.Save("RestServConv.xml")
End Sub

Public Function renameNodes(ByVal TopNode As XmlNode) As Boolean
    Dim UseNode As XmlNode

    If TopNode.Name <> "#text" Then
        If TopNode.Name = "tr" Then
            UseNode = RenameNode(TopNode, "citation")
        ElseIf TopNode.Name = "table" Then
            UseNode = RenameNode(TopNode, "results")
            UseNode.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem("id")
        ElseIf TopNode.Attributes.Count > 0 Then
            For Each oAttribute As XmlAttribute In TopNode.Attributes
                If oAttribute.Name = "class" Then
                    UseNode = RenameNode(TopNode, oAttribute.Value)
                    UseNode.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem("class")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next oAttribute
        End If

        If UseNode IsNot Nothing Then
            If UseNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0 Then
                Dim x As Integer
                For x = 0 To UseNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1
                    renameNodes(UseNode.ChildNodes(x))
                Next x
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return True
End Function

Public Shared Function RenameNode(ByVal e As XmlNode, ByVal newName As String) As XmlNode
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = e.OwnerDocument
    Dim newNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateNode(e.NodeType, newName, Nothing)
    While (e.HasChildNodes)
        newNode.AppendChild(e.FirstChild)
    End While
    Dim ac As XmlAttributeCollection = e.Attributes
    While (ac.Count > 0)
        newNode.Attributes.Append(ac(0))
    End While
    Dim parent As XmlNode = e.ParentNode
    parent.ReplaceChild(newNode, e)
    Return newNode
End Function
```

I passed in your example document and the result I got was this:

```
<results>
  <citation>
    <_index>
      <uri href="REDACTED">1</uri>
    </_index>
    <au>
      <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">GILLESPIE JB</span>
      <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">KUKES RE</span>
    </au>
    <so rowspan="1" colspan="1">A.M.A. American Journal of Diseases of Children</so>
    <ti>Acetylsalicylic acid poisoning with recovery.</ti>
    <ui>20267726</ui>
    <yr>1947</yr>
  </citation>
  <citation>
    <_index>
      <uri href="REDACTED">2</uri>
    </_index>
    <au>BASS MH</au>
    <so>Journal of the Mount Sinai Hospital, New York</so>
    <ti>Aspirin poisoning in infants.</ti>
    <ui>20265054</ui>
    <yr>1947</yr>
  </citation>
</results>
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for going into such detail!  I will ultimately mark this as the answer, but I note that the first of the <so> elements in your output now contains rowspan and colspan, where did they come from?

Comment: So after going over your post I see that in my code I neglected to use an XMLNamespaceManager.  I added one and used it in the initial node select and the problem I was having disappeared!  I still don't really understand why, but the issue is indeed resolved.  Thanks a million!

Comment: you know I failed to notice that they were in there. I think I added them by hand when I was trying to force the error you were getting. Other than that the reason you are probably seeing them is that the DTD specifies them in the attribute list.